# ObservableCollection<T> isn't getting notified of change in property of <T>

Tags: c#, wpf, events, mvvm

I have a an ObservableCollection of Component, a class with another ObservableCollection, a String and a ComponentVersion. The SelectedComponentVersion is being updated via my view correctly but I'm unable to get the property of Components to fire it's setter/OnPropertyChanged.

```
private ObservableCollection<Component> components
public ObservableCollection<Component> Components
{
   get { return foo; }
   set { foo = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
}
```

Here is the class of Component.

```
public class Component : ViewModelBase
{
  private string componentName;
  private ObservableCollection<ComponentVersion> componentVersions;
  private ComponentVersion selectedComponent;

  public string ComponentName
  {
     get { return componentName; }
     set { componentName = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
  }
  public ObservableCollection<ComponentVersion> ComponentVersions
  {
     get { return componentVersions; }
     set { componentVersions = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
  }
  public ComponentVersion SelectedComponent
  {
     get { return selectedComponent; }
     set { selectedComponent = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
  }

  public Component(string componentName, List<ComponentVersion> componentVersion)
  {
     ComponentName = componentName;
     ComponentVersions = componentVersion.ToObservableCollection();
  }
}
```

I then have a binding from a listview onto the SelectedComponent property inside of Component.

I have read countless stack overflows about setting up CollectionChanged and have tried to implement it with no luck.

```
Components.CollectionChanged += stuff;
private void stuff(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
   throw new System.NotImplementedException();
}
```

but this is never hit as tested with breakpoints.

Am I missing something entirely, losing my mind or daft! Someone please give me a point in the right direction, if any of this makes any sense at all.

P.S another solution I though of would be to place an invisible button inside the listview and have that send a command to tell the vm that a selected item has been updated.

Comment: You're assigning an event handler called `stuff` in your snippet, followed by a separate event handler called `ComponentVersions_CollectionChanged` that likely wasn't assigned. Am I missing something there?

Comment: Sorry fixed that now, was just an example of one of the things I had tried in my lostness. Wrote the first line in here and c+p the method from code and forgot to change the value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In cases like this where I want to do something when *the property on an item inside the collection changes*, I usually hook up a `PropertyChanged` event in the `CollectionChanged` event

Here's a code example :

```
public MyViewModel()
{
    // Setup Collection, with a CollectionChanged event
    Components = new ObservableCollection<Component>();
    Components.CollectionChanged += Components_CollectionChanged;

}

// In the CollectionChanged event (items getting added or removed from collection),
// hook up the PropertyChanged event
void Components_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.NewItems != null)
        foreach(MyType item in e.NewItems)
            item.PropertyChanged += Component_PropertyChanged;

    if (e.OldItems != null)
        foreach(MyType item in e.OldItems)
            item.PropertyChanged -= Component_PropertyChanged;
}

// In the PropertyChanged event, run some code if SelectedComponent property changed
void Component_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PropertyName == "SelectedComponent")
        DoWork();
}
```

Note that we are using two separate events here.

- `CollectionChanged` event runs when the collection itself changes. This means it gets set to a new collection, or item(s) get added or removed from the collection.

  This captures newly added items and hooks up the PropertyChanged
  handler, or detaches the PropertyChanged handler for items being
  removed from the collection.
- `PropertyChanged` event runs when a property changes and fires the event. You'll use this event to run code when the `SelectedComponent` property on any item in the collection changes

Comment: Is there any simple way to have it hook up to all the values at the start too as I'm setting it directly to a reference of an object

Comment: Ive done so for now by just running a foreach through each item in components and manually hooking it up

Comment: @user8478480 That is what I was going to suggest, just hooking up the PropertyChanged handler at the time it was initialized :)

Answer (score 2):

Well, `components` hasn't changed. I'm not sure if you set up your handler correctly, but even if you did, a CollectionChanged event is only fired, *if the collection changed* (item added or removed).

Lets say you have a collection of cars and all are red.

You pick one car and set it's color to blue.

The collection has not changed. It's still the very same cars. No car is missing, no car was added.

You probably want to attach yourself to the handlers of all cars instead of the handler of the collection.

So to sum it up:

> ObservableCollection<T> isn't getting notified of change in property of <T>

That's true and it's by design.

Comment: That does make sense guess I needed another view on it to realise that. Would it be right to look through the components in the constructor of my vm where that's located and attatch them all to fire an event or can I make use of the fact they all already call property changed?

Answer (score 2):

When adding items to the collection you want to "hook up" the events you are interested in for those items, then you can act as needed. As mentioned above, the collection isn't changing it is the individual items that are changing.

One thing you could do is extend the ObservableCollection class and override the functionality so that when the collection is changed, an item is either added or removed, you then go through the items in the collection and "hook up" the events you're interested in. One thing to note is you may have to go through the collection and remove the event handlers and "hook up" them again in order to stop getting multiple event handlers being set for the items in the list.

Comment: I tried an implementation of this but wasn't able to quite get it working. Will give it a try again tomorrow, I do get the concept tho thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`ObservableCollection<T>` does not send notifications about property changes of the elements. However, the `System.ComponentModel` namespace contains another collection, which supports that: you can consider to use `BindingList<T>` instead, which is also supported by WPF (elements must implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`).

Please note though that `BindingList<T>` scales poorly and its performance starts to decline above hundreds and thousands of elements as it always searches for the changed element sequentially in order to return the element index in its `ListChanged` event.

Comment: Hi this sounds like a good idea for what I'm doing. Was that meant as hundreds and thousands, 100,000's. For my project there won't be many implementing it, easily under a hundred. Thank you, will give it a try tomorrow